# Search for occurences of multiple variables stored in an array using Wordpress wp_query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, session, sql-like

This should be easy to solve and I think has something to do with my use of LIKE, but I just can't see the wood for the trees!

I have defined a custom post type (CPT) called COURSES. Using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), the COURSES CPT has a column called TEACHERS. ACF stores a lot of data in the TEACHERS column, including unique IDs for each teacher.

$_SESSION['search_teachers'] is filled by a multiple select field in a form and contains the teacher IDs I want to search the TEACHERS column by. It can contain any number of teacher IDs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$teachers = implode($_SESSION['search_teachers'],',');

$args_courses = array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
            'posts_per_page' => 9999,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'active',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'teachers',
                    'value' => $teachers,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
            'orderby' => 'course_name',
            'order'   => 'ASC'
        );
```

Please note I am using:

```
'key' => 'active', 'value' => 1, 'compare' => '='
```

in my WP_query to filter if the course is currenty active.

My WP_query works fine if $_SESSION['search_teachers'] contains ONLY 1 teacher ID. How do I make it work when $_SESSION['search_teachers'] contains multiple teacher IDs?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
This is what is contained in my teachers column:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"509";i:1;s:3:"511";i:2;s:3:"514";}
```

And this is what is contained in my $_SESSION['search_teachers']:

```
Array ( [0] => 511 [1] => 514 )
```

Comment: Think of what your query would do: it would generate `WHERE .. teachers LIKE 'teacher1,teacher2'`. You probably want `IN`.

Comment: or, you can try with an `EXISTS`.

Comment: @Kenney: there's `find_in_set()` for this kind of thing, but it ain't exactly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

See class `WP_Meta_Query` in `wp-includes/meta.php`, referenced from `wp-includes/query.php`.

```
$teachers = $_SESSION['search_teachers'];   // keep as array

...
          array(
                'key' => 'teachers',
                'value' => $teachers,      // an array of strings
             // 'compare' => 'IN'          // this is default if $teachers is an array
          )
```

**UPDATE**

Given the value of the teachers column to be

```
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"509";i:1;s:3:"511";i:2;s:3:"514";}
```

which is [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)d data,
there is no reliable way to query this using SQL. Such data is intended to be used at the PHP level, not by the database. It's best to simply use multiple `postmeta` entries, which will work just fine with the solution I gave above.

You could try to 'hack' this in the following way, but 1) I do not recommend it because it may give false positives if the structure of the serialized data is changed, and 2) it is not possible:

```
'meta_query' => array_merge(
    array(
        'key' => 'active',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '='
    ),

    // TODO: 'OR'
    array_map( function($teacher_id) {
        return array(
            'key' => 'teachers',
            'value' => "%\"$teacher_id\"%",
            'compare => 'LIKE'
        );
    } )
),
```

As you see, we need to somehow turn this into

```
WHERE ... 
  (active = 1 AND (
      teachers LIKE '%"ID_1"%'
   OR teachers LIKE '%"ID_2"%'
   OR teachers LIKE '%"ID_3"%'
  ))
```

but [this is not possible with `meta_query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35683/meta-query-with-and-or).

As I said earlier, you should use a multi-valued meta, like this:

```
table wp_postmeta:

meta_id | post_id | meta_key    | meta_value
--------+---------+-------------+------------
 1000   |  20000  | teacher     | 509
 1001   |  20000  | teacher     | 511
 1002   |  20000  | teacher     | 514
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny but compare => IN is returning 0 results as well. I've adjusted the question to make it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, that is  [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data; you cannot really use that safely in SQL, because when the structure changes and numbers are added you get false positives. Also it's pretty hard to find multiple strings in multiple positions in SQL this way. I'll update the question with a solution, but I don't recommend it.